# bytes to sbytes and back - C# NAudio

Tags: c#, naudio

I need to normalize an 8 bit audio .wav file.

I used NAudio to load the file to a `byte[]`.  I successfully converted this to an `sbyte[]` and recovered the sine bit.  I then multiply this array (casting to a `float`) to get the normalized value (0-255) hard limited.

Now I need to save it back as a `byte[]` to let NAudio write it.   The problem is, if I just cast,

```
source[i] = (byte)normalizedFloatArray[i];
```

The resulting saved .wav looks like this! Ouch.

[image: goofy wave]

"goofy wave"

Where might the problem lie?

Comment: could you please post the way you convert from `byte` to `sbyte`? I think there might be something wrong at this point.

Comment: Don't convert to sbyte.  Convert to float and subtract 127.

Comment: @HansPassant Shouldn't he subtract 128?  The `sbyte` range is [-128, 127].

Comment: Well, depends how the original signal was converted to bytes.  It doesn't matter in practice, it is just a DC offset.

Comment: All of that is great info.  I ended up using Hans Passant's strategy, and basically giving up on casting.  I just subtracted 128, scaled based on byte.MaxValue/2,  and then added 128 back and wrote out the new byte[].  Works.

Answer (score 2):

I think that happens because of how a byte gets converted to an sbyte. Example:

```
sbyte b1 = 100;
sbyte b2 = -100;
Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", b1, (byte)b1);
Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", b2, (byte)b2);
```

This outputs the following:

```
100 = 100
-100 = 156
```

So if your wave looks the following in sbytes:

```
{ 0, 50, 100, 50, 0, -50, -100, -50, 0 }
```

The output will be the following in bytes:

```
{ 0, 50, 100, 50, 206, 156, 206, 0 }
```

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites.

Comment: Sorry, it was my first post here. I fixed it

Answer (score 1):

Casting a `byte` to an `sbyte` causes positive values greater than `sbyte.MaxValue` to overflow and become negative values, which may not be what you want.  For example, while `(sbyte)127` yields `127`, `(sbyte)128` yields `-128`.  It may be that you want to translate the value range from `[0, 255]` to `[-128, 127]`, in which case you can simply offset each `byte` by `-128`:

```
signedByte = (sbyte)(unsignedByte + sbyte.MinValue)
```

Comment: Yes, your cast looks much nicer than mine. I ended up using a float, but essentially did the same thing.  This audio stuff is tricky.  Thanks again.

Comment: Yeah, the intermediate `sbyte` representation is unnecessary if you're only going to be working with the `float` values.  I used it to keep the answer more generalized.